# Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add sheets using: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add`

I am able to add one sheet but when I try to add two sheets it give me an error: Application defined or object defined error.

Here is the code to adding sheets:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=2, Type:="C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\TestWorksheet.xltm")
Set ws = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

When I change the `Count:=1` it works fine, it displays error for `Count:=2`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Count" will only work when you are trying to add **xlWorksheet (Which is by default)**, **xlChart**, **xlExcel4MacroSheet**, or **xlExcel4IntlMacroSheet**.

For example

```
Sub Sample1()
     Dim ws As Worksheet

     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=5, Type:=xlWorksheet)

     Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Even if you don't include xlWorksheet, it is ok as it is taken by default.

When you are adding from a template you have to do it in a loop. For example

```
Sub Sample2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    i = 1

    Do While i < 3 '<~~ Adding 2 times
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), _
        Type:="C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\TestWorksheet.xltm")
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Set ws = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I got it to work, I had declared "ws" as "Sheets" defining it as "worksheet" got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: If I insert more than one of a particular sheet the second sheet is named with a (2) after its name. For e.g. If I am inserting 2 "Student" sheets. The first one is Named "Student" and the second one is named "Student(2)" is there any way to name the first sheet "Student(1)" for consistency?

Answer (score 2):

It's because your setting it as `WS` which is defined as a worksheet.  So it can't contain multiple worksheets

Comment: Defining it as worksheets also gives the same error, How else would I define it?

Comment: @user793468 Sorry, my point was that it's not possible.  When you use the `Set` you are setting an object, 2 worksheets can't be a object.

Comment: @user793469 Further more, you only need to use `Set` if you require to reference that object again in your code.  If you take of the `Set ws =` then you can add multiple sheets with just that one line of code